# Получение числа вместо строки из словаря ENUM_E_MACHINE

Tags: python, словари

В файле формата `ELF` хранится тип архитектуры. В `pyelftools` существует словарь :

```
ENUM_E_MACHINE = dict
(
    EM_NONE  = 0, # No machine
    EM_M32   = 1, # AT&T WE 32100
    EM_SPARC = 2, # SPARC
    ...
)
```

Пользовательский интерфейс приспособлен для возврата строк из этого `enum`.

Но требуется достать число из словаря (получается достать строку). Например :

```
print something.elf['e_machine'] 
print something.elf.header.e_machine
```

Выводит он строку. Например, `EM_X86_64` или `EM_M32`.
Как посредством этой библиотеки прямо или косвенно получать число из словаря, соответсвующее типу машины, а не строку?

Comment: из сказанного не следует ли вариант:
`ENUM_E_MACHINE[something.elf['e_machine'] ]`
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если `something.elf['e_machine'] == 'EM_M32'`, а вы хотите получить `1`, то просто как с обычным словарём достаньте значение по ключу `value = d[key]`:

```
print(ENUM_E_MACHINE[something.elf['e_machine']]) # -> 1
```

Comment: блин @jfs - списал ответ из моего коммента, так хоть мне лайк на комментарий киньте кто нибудь?!
Куда катится мир ;-)

Comment: @VasylKolomiets если вы думаете, что мне нужно читать комментарии, чтобы на такой вопрос ответить, то вы ошибаетесь:) Никогда не перестаёт удивлять на каком простом коде люди спотыкаются. А ответы следует писать в ответах.

Comment: !  всякий раз, когда я отвечаю на такие вопросы - меня минусили.
Решил - что правильно отвечать в комментах... Ну ладно.
С наступающими праздниками ))))

Comment: @VasylKolomiets: и этому ответу тоже минус поставили. Не обращайте внимания, главное чтобы автору вопроса и будущим читателям из гугла с похожей проблемой ваши ответы помогали.